# How to solve error creating app in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I've installed react js in my pc. I tried to create a app in react in cmd by `create-react-app react-app` but it gave me following error:

```
C:\Users\Ahnaaf Al Rafee>create-react-app react-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Ahnaaf Al Rafee\react-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ahnaaf Al Rafee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-10T18_28_37_892Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-app / from C:\Users\Ahnaaf Al Rafee
Done.
```

Comment: are u having good net connection? wats ur node and npm version?

Comment: It looks like the download of eslint took too long so the install script timed out. Have you tried installing a second time?

Comment: my node version is `v12.16.3` and npm version is `6.14.4`. And I also have a good net connection. I tried to install 4 or 5 times, same case!

Comment: Check if there is a firewall or VPN blocking the connection.

Comment: To debug try custom installing any package from NPM Repository to know if there is any problem connecting that domain.

Comment: try running `npm config set cache "C:\Users\Ahnaaf~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global` and try again

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your internet connection might be slow. Try increasing the timeout in your `.npmrc`

Comment: i don't think so. my net connection is good. what did u say about `.npmrc`? I didn't understand

Comment: If you are on Windows, find the .npmrc file in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`

change `timeout=50000`

Try `create-react-app`

Comment: i have found .npmrc file. But i can't open it. How do i solve this?

Comment: Open with Notepad? @AhnaafAlRafee

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it might help

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: share the error log, lets see if we find some detail in that to debug.

Comment: ps: you did try your npm install after this cache clean command. right?